# How to import only the class that I'll use dynamically on Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, dynamic, import

I have an application that has many classes and a class that handle one of that classes (choosed by user) using polymorphism. Is there a way to import and use only the class that the user asked?

Example: I have three files, Animal class and Pig and Dog, that extends Animal. I also have an file that calls Animal.walk(). If the user select Dog, all the data of Pig file will be useless so I dont have to import it, is that possible?

Because I will have more than 30 different files.

I've tried to import dynamically using template strings but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Import statement does not allow template strings or string concatenation in the file path.

You can use require() to dynamically import files by using template literals or string concatenation.

If you are in a situation where you cannot use require() in your project (probably you have set type:module in package.json) You can try the [dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)